# Virtualbox: VBoxDrv broken since windows upudate

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have seen similar posts stating that a crypt32.dll has been broken with recent windows updates, but I am having a slightly different problem. Mine is that NtCreateFile(\DeviceVBoxDrvStub) failed. The error box suggests that I run sc.exe. When I run sc.exe, it says that the service does not exist as an installed service.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by Update [KB3004394](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3004394/en-us).

Install the fix from this KB to resolve the issue:

**Install KB3024777 to fix an issue with KB3004394 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2**
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/3024777/en-us